# cursor_div wont follow the cursor when I scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mousemove

When Im at the top of the page. The curose_div will follow the cursor perfectly. But when I start scrolling to the bottom the cursor_div position will not follow correctly.

Heres my code

```
<div id="cursor"</div></div id="cursor_border"></div>
```

`var cursor = $('#cursor');
var cursor_border = $('#cursor_border');

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    console.log(e.pageY + ' and '+ e.pageX ) ;

    
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    cursor.css("left",x+'px');
    cursor.css("top",y+'px');
    
    cursor_border.css("left",x+'px');
    cursor_border.css("top",y+'px');`
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code that shows the error? Because when I copy>paste your code into a JSFiddle there is no error. I did remove jQuery though. https://jsfiddle.net/zch307t1/3/

Comment: @Kokodoko Your example captures the essence of the problem. When scrolling, if you do not move the mouse, the cursor moves along with the scroll.

Comment: Ah that's because when the mouse doesn't move, the listener won't get triggered. Maybe the better approach would be to set the cursor using CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` together with `#cursor { position: fixed; }`:

```js
window.onmousemove = event => cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(${event.clientX}px, ${event.clientY}px, 0)`;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightgreen, lightblue);
}

#cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: none;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  will-change: transform;
}

#cursor[style] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may correct the error :

```
  function updateCursor() {
  cursor.style.left = mouseX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = mouseY + 'px';

  cursorBorder.style.left = mouseX + 'px';
  cursorBorder.style.top = mouseY + 'px';

  requestAnimationFrame(updateCursor);
}

updateCursor();
```

The use of classic Javascript can improve the performance, and may correct the error caused by jQuery !
I hope this helped you !